# iPad Safari: How to disable the quick blinking effect when a link has been hit

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

Is there any way to disable that?
I only mean in the browser... When you click a link or a button or a div that has a click function on it, it flickers a grey box where you clicked quickly. How do i prevent this?

Comment: Why would you want to?  It's so the user knows they actually activated something... it's very helpful.

Comment: Basically, I have a div over top of a large image. When they double click it it zooms in. (I have disabled the zooming option for other reasons) and when you click it once, it allows a toolbar to show up or disappear. Since this div is transparent I don't want it to flicker everytime they click on it. However, I am keeping it on most of my other buttons.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You could set a transparent color to the [`-webkit-tap-highlight-color` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_tap_highlight_color) of that element.

```
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: ie: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`

Comment: Very cool, thanks.  I added it to the container div which encompasses my mobile app, but assume that you could add it to the body element like this too:  body {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}

Comment: For the record, an app I am making in Phonegap kept having a short flicker when tapping on elements, and it was just noticeable to bug me. Setting `-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent` to everything (i.e. `*`) worked like a charm.

Comment: Charlie - The issue you're seeing is because Webkit seems to briefly apply the highlight color to the item once it becomes inactive. Rather than setting a global rule like that, adding `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` to the inactive state of the targeted link solves the issue.

Comment: Just want to add that using `webkit-tap-highlight-color: none` does *not* work. You actually have to set transparency via `rgba(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: Is it possible to add it to the whole body?  So you don't have to define css for each clickable element? Something like `body { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important; }`

Answer (score 10):

Using mobile Safari in Phonegap, only this worked:

```
* {  -webkit-backface-visibility:  hidden;
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color:  transparent;
  }
```

Source: [iPhone WebKit CSS animations cause flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker)

Also, on the main panel, enable rendering:

```
div.myPanelOrWhatever 
  {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
```

Source: [Prevent flicker on webkit-transition of webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform)

Comment: Is there a Mozilla version I need to worry about?