# Prevent gray rectangle flickering when image is clicked on android

Tags: android, html, css

I am positioning several images using absolute positioning within a web page and linking them to different pages inside my web application. When I tap on the images, a gray rectangular section gets highlighted momentarily and then the page is transfered to the destination page.

Found [iPad Safari: How to disable the quick blinking effect when a link has been hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516173/ipad-safari-how-to-disable-the-quick-blinking-effect-when-a-link-has-been-hit) but it does not work on the android.

Do any of you know how to prevent this behavior? It does not happen on the iPad.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
html,*{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```