# iOS - On "click" have background blink like this example. How do I achieve that effect?

Tags: ios, css, mobile, safari

So here's an example of what I'm talking about.

When you open [this website](http://democloud.argentotheme.com/flatfullen/), open chrome devtools, and emulate an iPad (or just open it on an iPad), any time you `touchstart` on anything, a "blink" happens.

Specifically, I want to know how to remove that effect.

It's not a `background` change that I can see, I do not see any `animation` value applied anywhere, and it doesn't look like it's a `pseudo-element`, and I cannot find any `focus` or `active` styles on any elements around there.

How do I recreate this effect, and, more importantly, how do I remove it if I want to?

[image: iOS simulator on click]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516173/ipad-safari-how-to-disable-the-quick-blinking-effect-when-a-link-has-been-hit

Comment: ^ this is the correct answer. Thanks Mr Bottens!