# -webkit-transition-property for translation

Tags: iphone, debugging, css, transform

Hai.
What is the transition property for translations in CSS3? I'm currently using `all` but I got a bug in iOS so I want to test another property.

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-320px, 0);
```

```
-webkit-transition: ??? .5 ease-in-out;
```

See the bug with an iOS device [here](http://sexyprout.github.com/exp/trickle.html) (swipe horizontally), there's a kind of flash.

---

**Update**: to anyone interested, I found a way to fix it thanks to Duopixel:

```
E {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); // perform an "invisible" translation
}

// Then you can translate with translate3d(), no bug!
document.querySelector('E').webkitTransform = 'translate3d(-320px, 0, 0)'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are tons of things you can transition, the easiest to test in my experience is opacity.

However, I've encountered the flashing problem before, try:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px, 0, 0);
```

This will kick in hardware acceleration, which fixes the problem and makes the animation extremely smooth.

Comment: I still got a flash at the first swipe, then it disappears. I think I'll have to deal with it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker

Answer (score 21):

Your solution will work, however it the exact answer you were looking for is -webkit-transform.

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Incase it doesn't work for anyone, add an 's' after the '.5' to make '.5s'