# Div doesn't read click events with backface-visibility: hidden

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, mobile-safari, css-transitions

I'm trying to fade in a div in a webapp I'm building for iPad. The iPad chokes trying to use jQuery's fadeIn() method so I'm trying to do the transition with `-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear` and changing the opacity to 0 or 1 with javascript. It looks pretty smooth, except that it flickers once quite jarringly at the end of the fade.

As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814101/css3-transition-transform-translate3d-causes-severe-flicker-on-first-or-last-fra) a while back, this flicker instantly disappears when I set `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`. Unfortunately, when I have that set, the div no longer detects the click or touchstart events used to dismiss it. I'm very confident this is the problem because when I remove that property in the inspector, it will read clicks perfectly. I found someone else mention a similar bug in a comment on SO but no solution was given.

Does anyone have any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was that the divs I was trying to read the click on were in a collapsed 0x0 div. It's a bit bizarre that `backface-visibility` would make or break that, but I was able to fix the problem by making the previously collapsed container full size and adding js to turn it display block and none at various times.