# css3 transitions cause flickering on iPad

Tags: ios, html, css, css-transitions

I wrote some animations using CSS3 transitions and it works well on desktop browsers, but when I tried to use it on iPad it does this weird flickering after the animation is done. Here is the link to the example:

http://codepen.io/EugeneGordin/full/LFBkn

I already applied [backface-visibility and translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814101/css3-transition-transform-translate3d-causes-severe-flicker-on-first-or-last-fr), and while they helped it has not removed the flicker. I have also removed any references to z-index and display: none, so I'm at a loss for further exploration.

I'm animating about 15 divs with translate3d and a few others with opacity, so I don't feel like I'm pushing the limits of what the hardware can handle. FWIW, I have tested on the micrososft surface and the animations look smooth there.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I suspect that this is simply an problem with the way mobile Safari (or, rather, mobile WebKit, as this seems to occur in iOS Chrome as well) renders CSS3 animations. I think the only solution might be reporting the bug to WebKit's developers, and waiting for a patch.

Comment: yeah...I think the same way, cause I really tried lots of different things and nothing helped...it works just fine on Surface! but under iOS it just doesn't want to work normally :(((