# Hover effecting other elements other than the item being hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having a hover issue. Whenever I hover over a specific `.servNavItemTitle` the font weight for the other `.servNavItemTitle` decreases for a moment and then goes back to normal quickly.

To see it in the demo, just hover over one of the titles and watch the other titles as the `font-weight` reduces.

Does anyone see what the issue is?

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q4fk1x75/)

Here is a narrowed down version of the code:

```css
.servNavItemWrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.servNavItemWrap img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.servNavItemWrap:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.servNavItemWrap a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.servNavItemTitle {
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.servNavItemWrap:hover .servNavItemTitle {
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div id="serviceNavBlock2" class="iblock">
  <div class="servNavItemWrap">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/profile.php">
      <img src="" alt="Aluminum Profile">
      <span class="servNavItemTitle hGc block">Aluminum</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="servNavItemWrap">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="" alt="Aluminum Components">
      <span class="servNavItemTitle hGc block">Components</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in chrome, what browser do you see the above behaviour in?

Comment: this the effect of the scaling

Comment: @Pete I am using Chrome and I see it happening.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is there anyway to resolve the issue? I have seen scaling before that didn't effect the text under it.

Answer (score 2):

After Temani narrowed down the issue, I searched and found the answer here: [css transform element affects other element which use transform:scale(0.5) in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081168/css-transform-element-affects-other-element-which-use-transformscale0-5-in-an) . Basically, I added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the scaled image and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Here is the forked fiddle with the fix implemented:
https://jsfiddle.net/7as2ydgn/