# CSS translate(0,5px) is making things wiggle on the X axis

Tags: css, css-transitions, antialiasing

I have a css translate happening on hover. It only affects the Y axis but it is jumping around. This makes the hover effect look wonky.

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0,5px);
```

The effect is on the main navigation. You can see it here: http://pineriver.com

Is this related to rounding or text pixel snapping? If so, I don't like it :)
You can see I've already tried tricks like `opacity:.99`.

I've worked around the problem by by using traditional `top:` and `bottom:` to do the translations, but I still am curious why this happens. I would really like to be able to use css translates to do visual butter things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting problem, but I'm going to give all the credit to google.

To the nav.primary ul li and .siteHeader .siteLogo rule add this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I found the idea [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/) and [here](http://blog.kamicrafted.com/post/30975461074/quick-fix-for-twitching-text-images-when-using-css).

Also [here is some more reading from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker).  They're talking about iPhone dev but it's still webkit.

Comment: That's odd. Is there any explanation on why a 2D transform is messing up with 3D stuff?

Comment: Wow. This is like a throwback to the olden days of hasLayout. An invisible switch. http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Oh, Firefox has a similar wiggle, by the way.