# Font Weight (incorrectly) Lighter in Mac Safari Only

Tags: css, macos, fonts, safari, font-face

**This problem exists ONLY on Mac Safari**.
Other browsers / other OS works properly.

The problem:
Observe the font weight of the top navigation here: http://www.octa.com (WordPress)

Then observe the font weight of the top navigation here: http://www.octa.com/products (Magento)

*Note* that while they are served by different code (WP vs Magento), the css is nearly identical between the two pages.

Here's the relevant bits of the css:

```
nav.menu li a {
    font-family: 'VegurLight','Myriad Pro',Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

nav.menu li a, #subnavwrapper nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 46px 0 0;
}

nav li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-    serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.55em;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
}
```

Note that the font is imported using @font-face.

I've tried everything - many answers here on SO and other articles. Note that **none** of the below styles gleaned from other answers / resources corrected the font display.

```
font-variant:normal;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 0 0 1px;
```

Comment: The pages are different on Win 7 Safari, too: https://www.octa.com has the navigation items with letters that look partly thinner in a broken way, though this seems to vary according to some dynamic changes on the page. (You should have explained what you see, instead of just saying “observe”.) You should identify the CSS differences and try to isolate the issue in a simple setup, instead of expecting others to debug your site. There are 26 markup errors on the main page, two of them seem to relate to references to stylesheets.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - thank you.  I assume you're using the w3c validator to check the markup for errors, or are you using another tool?  And FYI, I *did* compare css, it's identical.  Also, I *did* try and simplify, but the simplified version does not have the same problem.

Comment: You wrote in the question “the css is nearly identical”. If it really identical, then the problem is apparently somewhere else – in code that was not included in the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Good point.  Also, I'm realizing that the WP has plugin code that is likely having an impact (and is responsible for many of the markup errors you discovered).  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments / prodding from @JukkaK.Korpela, I discovered a few things:

First, the root of the problem is this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Which was added to the code to solve an animation problem per this answer: [iPhone WebKit CSS animations cause flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker)

Don't know how to solve the font **and** solve the flicker, but I can at least choose which one to solve now.

Second, as an avid Firefox/Firebug user, I had tried using Firebug Lite in Safari, as well as another extension for Safari, and they did not work.  So, for all of you out there who may be trying to troubleshoot Safari-only issues, here's a big tip:

Safari's "Develop" tool.  Didn't know about it at all until I did some searching today, but it's a menu item in the toolbar.  If you don't see it, then go to Preferences->Advanced, and check the "Show Develop Menu in Toolbar"

With that tool, I was able to troubleshoot and solve this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

I've found that this simple change made Safari's font-weight property much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

(I cannot post comments so I can only add my findings to the conversation by posting.)

I have found that text in **fixed position elements appears lighter** weight than other types of positioning **in Safari**. Therefore could not be ignored as suggested in other places.

Adding `--webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` does solve this , but then it looks lighter than in Firefox. Which can be fixed with  `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale`

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xevw5d/1/) to show the problem - Safari only