# BX slider, transition from first to last slide flickers(goes right then come back to original)

Tags: slide, bxslider, flicker

Following is my code for simple implementation for BX slider:

```
var slider = $('#bxslider').bxSlider();

<ul id="bxslider">
    <li>
        <img class="carouselimage" src="images/01e_image.jpg" />

    </li>
    <li >
        <img class="carouselimage" src="images/01c_image.jpg" />

    </li>
    <li >
        <img class="carouselimage" src="images/01a_image.jpg" />

    </li>
</ul>
```

I've used everything correctly, no extra CSS and JS.

While I make the transition by clicking left arrow from first to last (reverse), the last slide goes towards the right out of the container for a sec and comes back to original, looks like a flickering.

Anybody got any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got this fixed.. if anyone else needs..

i've added

```
"if (0===value) value=-40;// fix for flickering issue 2208141730"
```

in following function, you can find this function in BxSlider v4.1.2(jquery.bxslider.js) at line no. 535 and above fix is added at line no. 539

```
var setPositionProperty = function(value, type, duration, params){
    // use CSS transform
    if(slider.usingCSS){
        // determine the translate3d value
        if (0===value) value=-40;// fix for flickering issue 2208141730
```

Comment: It is so wrong to modify a plugin. Have you made a pull request on github ?

Answer (score 12):

I fix it that way:

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  useCSS: false
});

(thanks to stevenwanderski on https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/127)

Answer (score 4):

My co-worker had this issue, she used this on bxslider

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

See here [iPhone WebKit CSS animations cause flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker)

Answer (score 0):

Update this in bxslider plugin:

```
var setPositionProperty = function(value, type, duration, params){
  // use CSS transform
  if(slider.usingCSS){
    // determine the translate3d value
    var propValue = slider.settings.mode == 'vertical' ? 'translateX(' + value + 'px)' : 'translateX(' + value + 'px)';
```

Add new css

```
.bx-viewport ul{
   backface-visibility: visible;
   perspective: 2000;
   -webkit-perspective: 2000;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```