# Flickering issue on iPhone when using Transition CSS

Tags: html, iphone, css, transition

For the flickering issue on iPhone when using Transition CSS, for example this link: [iPhone WebKit CSS animations cause flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker/3934275#3934275)
 My question is what exactly "-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}" does conceptually that solves this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}` activates [hardware acceleration](https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d): iOS uses its GPU instead of CPU and the result is way smoother.
Translating by 0 pixel in 3 directions doesn't change anything to the position of your pixels so it's safe, except if it overrides an existing transform.

EDIT: it's been one way of activating GPU for a few years now but - broadening your question - it's not the only one and Chrome is changing or has changed its compositing/layer system. I didn't follow thoroughly these changes or new ways of activating it but you'll learn a lot by viewing demos on YT by Paul Irish, the Chromium blog, [Google Devs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/devtools-timeline-now-providing-the-full-story) or [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/)

Comment: Thanx for the explanation. Seems justified to me but I still have a small doubt. For example, I have an html page with a fixed header and a horizontal slider on it somewhere using horizontal scroll property which also uses a transition property. Now, when the slider scrolls to the end then the fixed element(Header) flickers. As far as I understand there is no transition on header then why does it affect the header. I would be grateful If you'd like to spare a few minutes again.