# Why are my APNGs glitching in Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, webkit, mobile-safari, apng

I have these APNGs on my art portfolio website. They look fine on desktop Safari, but occasionally flicker (changes in color and parts of the APNG disappear) in safari on iOS.

https://artadriana.com/alison

Another person also viewed it on mobile, and they experience the same problem.

I'm not sure if the problem is in my code, or in my images.

```
<h1>SAMPLE STICKERS</h1>
<div class="three-column-grid" id="alison2-side-by-side">
    <img src="/assets/images/27.png">
    <img src="/assets/images/17.png">
    <img src="/assets/images/25.png">
</div>

<div class="three-column-grid" id="alison2-side-by-side">
    <img src="/assets/images/6.png">
    <img src="/assets/images/12.png">
    <img src="/assets/images/14.png">
</div>

<div class="three-column-grid" id="alison2-side-by-side">
    <img src="/assets/images/29.png">
    <img src="/assets/images/36.png">
    <img src="/assets/images/33.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having what sounds like the same issue, but all I can think is it's an actual Safari rendering bug - it is fine in all other browsers.

Comment: same problem in my iOS.I fixed with the blog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker